# mysqldump only if the database is available

Tags: mysql

To get a dump from a mysql database I use,

```
mysqldump -u root -p my_db --databases --add-drop-database  --no-data --skip-triggers   >> ./mydump
```

It works fine and create the dump. But now what I want is before creating the dumpfile I want to check whether or not the database is available, and only create the dumpfile if the database is available.

Is there a way to do that check before the dump is created?

Comment: @krishnan Hi use shell script to list all the mysql files first then store the file name to one variable and use for in to find the database der or not.........

Comment: thanks a lot Malai.. I did it using a shell script

Answer (score 0):

```
DBAVAILABLE="$(mysql -u root -p[pass] -Bse 'show databases like "required_db"')"


if [ "$DBAVAILABLE" == "" ]; then
    echo "Database not available locally!";
    echo
    exit
fi

mysqldump -u root -p my_db --databases --add-drop-database --no-data --skip-triggers >> ./mydump
```

Answer (score 0):

Steps :

```
1. first check u r databases files are stored in mysql folder or not...
2.get that file names using shell script
3.store the file name to array...
4.use for loop and if condition to dump db
```